Navbar Toggler problems - Do we still need JQuery?
I am looking at Bootstrap v5.3.3 and having problems with the navbar-toggler opening the menu. The icon shows up properly, but clicking on it does nothing. I seem to remember having to include JQuery at one time, but I don't see anything about it on the getbootstrap web site. Do we still need to include it?
I have tried the page on 2 (maybe 3) different browsers. I have looked at the other posting here however, none seem to be less than 10yrs old. What am I missing.
In the <head> tag
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title><?= $title ?></title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>

At end of the <body> tag
     <!-- Javascripts -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>

The navbar code
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-pink" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?= $title ?></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuItems" aria-controls="menuItems" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#page-top">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#listen">Listen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#comments">Comments</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#stations">Our Family</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


Bootstrap does not use jQuery starting with v5.

Found the answer in this post
enter link description here

Also note that data-toggle and data-target have changed too:
data-toggle => data-bs-toggle
data-target => data-bs-target

I noticed that I had a data-target in my code :(
